# Function call a for loop

Tags: c, function, call

I'm trying to function call the for loop and print AngleValue and SinValue, but whatever I do I can't get it to work. All I need is to print those 2 from the loop into the main function.

```
int trigof(int x, double y, double AngleValue, double SinValue);
int main(void)
{

    printf("%35s","***************************\n");
    printf("%35s","****TABLE OF SIN VALUES****\n");
    printf("%35s","***************************\n");
    printf("%17s", "ANGLE(DEG)");
    printf("%18s","SIN(ANGLE)\n");

        printf("Press any key to exit");
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }//endprogram

int trigof(int x, double y, double AngleValue, double SinValue)
{

for (x = 0; x < 18; x++)
    {
        y = AngleValue * PI / 180;
        SinValue = sin(y);
        printf("%13.1f", AngleValue);
        printf("%18.4f\n", SinValue);
        AngleValue = AngleValue + 20.0;


    }
    return AngleValue;
    return SinValue;
}
```

Comment: What does not work? What is your expected result? what  is your actual result? How did you try to debug it?

Comment: In C you can't define a function inside the body of another function. They must all be defined separately. `main` is a function, and you are trying to define `trigof` inside `main`. You can call it in `main`; you just can't define it inside `main`.

Comment: I can't get what is your question.

Comment: trigOf function is not called anywhere in the main function. That is why nothing is printing. but there is missing value for PI and other issues in the code as well.

Answer (score 5):

First of all there are lots of mistakes.
You have declared function but you haven't called it in your main. To call function inside main use this statement inside main function `trigof(0,0,45,0);` 45 is the angle value. Secondly you don't need x, y, signvalue as function parameters. You can declare them locally inside your trigof function. Lastly there should be only one return statement returning only one object.

Answer (score 4):

```
#define PI (4*atan(1))

static void trigOf(void);

int main(void) {
    printf("%35s","***************************\n");
    printf("%35s","****TABLE OF SIN VALUES****\n");
    printf("%35s","***************************\n");
    printf("%17s", "ANGLE(DEG)");
    printf("%18s","SIN(ANGLE)\n");
    trigOf();
    printf("Press any key to exit");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}//endprogram

static void trigof() {
    int x;
    double y=0.0,AngleValue=0.0,SinValue=0.0;
    for (x = 0; x < 18; x++) {
        y = AngleValue * PI / 180;
        SinValue = sin(y);
        printf("%13.1f", AngleValue);
        printf("%18.4f\n", SinValue);
        AngleValue = AngleValue + 20.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be better to make `trigof()` into a function that returns `void` because the value it returns is not used (and if a value were returned, it should probably be a `double`, not an `int`. Although the function is declared, it is not declared with a prototype. This is not ideal — a prototype is helpful for checking. Note that in C (as opposed to C++), `int trigof();` is a non-prototype declaration for a function with an unspecified (but fixed) number of arguments. Use `int trigof(void);` to explicitly say "no arguments".  Make the function `static` too since it isn't used anywhere else.

Comment: I know this was snippet code, but `3.14`????? That's way too few digits even for sample code. I routinely use `#define PI (4*atan(1))` (or just use `M_PI` on POSIX systems).

Answer (score 1):

**For starters...**

You have to **define global variables**.

```
    #define PI 3.14159265358979323846
```

Your **function prototype** is incorrect, it requires **no parameters** in this scenario.

```
    //this is wrong
    int trigof(int x, double y, double AngleValue, double SinValue);
    //this is right
    int trigof();
```

You never call the function trigof(); in main therefore you get **no results**.

```
        printf("%35s","***************************\n");
        printf("%35s","****TABLE OF SIN VALUES****\n");
        printf("%35s","***************************\n");
        printf("%17s", "ANGLE(DEG)");
        printf("%18s","SIN(ANGLE)\n");
        //you should have function call here
        trigof();
```

You simply need to **define your local variables in the function**.

example:

```
    int trigof()
    {
        //these are local variables
        int x;
        double y, AngleValue, SinValue;

            for (x = 0; x < 18; x++)
                {
                    y = AngleValue * PI / 180;
                    SinValue = sin(y);
                    printf("%13.1f", AngleValue);
                    printf("%18.4f\n", SinValue);
                    AngleValue = AngleValue + 20.0;
                }
        return AngleValue;
        return SinValue;
    }
```

**If** you want your output to resemble this:

```
   ***************************                                                                                                     
   ****TABLE OF SIN VALUES****                                                                                                     
   ***************************                                                                                                     
   ANGLE(DEG)       SIN(ANGLE)                                                                                                     
      0.0            0.0000                                                                                                        
     20.0            0.3419                                                                                                        
     40.0            0.6425                                                                                                        
     60.0            0.8658                                                                                                        
     80.0            0.9847                                                                                                        
    100.0            0.9850                                                                                                        
    120.0            0.8666                                                                                                        
    140.0            0.6437                                                                                                        
    160.0            0.3434                                                                                                        
    180.0            0.0016                                                                                                        
    200.0           -0.3404                                                                                                        
    220.0           -0.6413                                                                                                        
    240.0           -0.8650                                                                                                        
    260.0           -0.9844                                                                                                        
    280.0           -0.9852                                                                                                        
    300.0           -0.8673                                                                                                        
    320.0           -0.6450                                                                                                        
    340.0           -0.3448
```